# Find previous time gap and next time gap between non nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I have a data frame like:

```
A    B   datetime
10  NaN  12-03-2020  04:43:11
NaN 20   13-03-2020  04:43:11
NaN NaN  14-03-2020  04:43:11
NaN NaN  15-03-2020  04:43:11
NaN NaN  16-03-2020  04:43:11
NaN 50   17-03-2020  04:43:11
20  NaN  18-03-2020  04:43:11
NaN 30   19-03-2020  04:43:11
NaN NaN  20-03-2020  04:43:11
30  30   21-03-2020  04:43:11
40  NaN  22-03-2020  04:43:11
NaN 10   23-03-2020  04:43:11
```

The code which I'm using is :

```
df['timegap_in_min'] = np.where( ((df['A'].notna()) &(df[['B','c']].shift(-1).notna())),df['Datetime'].shift(-1) - df['timestamp'], np.nan)
df['timegap_in_min'] = df['timegap_in_min'].astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

The required output is:

```
A    B   datetime                prev_timegap    next_timegap
10  NaN  12-03-2020  04:43:11    NaN             24     
NaN 20   13-03-2020  04:43:11    NaN             NaN
NaN NaN  14-03-2020  04:43:11    NaN             NaN
NaN NaN  15-03-2020  04:43:11    NaN             NaN
NaN NaN  16-03-2020  04:43:11    NaN             NaN
NaN 50   17-03-2020  04:43:11    NaN             NaN
20  NaN  18-03-2020  04:43:11    24              24
NaN 30   19-03-2020  04:43:11    NaN             NaN
NaN NaN  20-03-2020  04:43:11    NaN             NaN
30  30   21-03-2020  04:43:11    24              24
40  NaN  22-03-2020  04:43:11    24              24
NaN 10   23-03-2020  04:43:11    NaN             NaN
```

Someone help me in correcting my logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just slightly customize your codes to the following codes:

```
df['prev_timegap'] = np.where( ((df['A'].notna()) & (df['B'].shift(1).notna())), abs(df['datetime'].shift(1) - df['datetime']), np.nan)
df['prev_timegap'] = df['prev_timegap'].astype('timedelta64[h]')

df['next_timegap'] = np.where( ((df['A'].notna()) & (df['B'].shift(-1).notna())), abs(df['datetime'].shift(-1) - df['datetime']), np.nan)
df['next_timegap'] = df['next_timegap'].astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

This should give you the desired result based on your description of requirement in the question title.  Anyway, the test result would be slightly different from the tabulated required output at the following row:

```
A    B   datetime                prev_timegap    next_timegap
...
30  30   21-03-2020  04:43:11    24              24
... 
...
```

instead, the result is:

```
A    B   datetime                prev_timegap    next_timegap
...
30  30   21-03-2020  04:43:11    NaN             NaN
... 
...
```

This result is based on you mentioned that "previous time gap and next time gap" (assuming "previous" and "next" are referring to different timeframe, i.e. different 'datetime').

Note that in your sample df, on column A with value 30, the corresponding value in B on the previous date and next date are both NaN.  Hence, should we show NaN instead ?

In case your requirement includes showing some values for the 2 time gaps when there are non NaN values in both "current" datetime of Column A and B, we may need to further enhance the codes above.